# access instancedMesh's sub-instance origin and tranform with pivot in three.js?

Tags: three.js, geometry-instancing

I'm working on a scene that may needs large amount of animating models.So I have to use *instancedMesh*.But i've encountered some transforming issues.Below is a instancing ferrari demo, i tried to **make the wheel rotating normally( around it's center)** but failed.since the meshes are already instanced, it's origin is already setted to the scene's origin.Is there any chance to use "pivot transformation" to the sub-instances and solve this problem? Thanks!.

[Instancing Ferrari Demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/instancing-ferrari-72hygp?file=%2Fsrc%2FflatternNode.js%3A16%2C14&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0006356ilo8j1nq4%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0002356iozyiy965%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0003356iqby7t3xv%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0005356i7ho63iz2%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B53.50215844834924%252C46.49784155165076%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clt4b9ftw0002356iozyiy965%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0001356ifhsbd0wi%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4bjvov0002356o4h4z3z2t%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A33%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A23%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A33%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A23%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4c5ym60002356omas7j57d%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A16%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A14%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A16%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A14%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FflatternNode.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0002356iozyiy965%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt4c5ym60002356omas7j57d%2522%257D%252C%2522clt4b9ftw0005356i7ho63iz2%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0004356iu1sz77xr%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0005356i7ho63iz2%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0004356iu1sz77xr%2522%257D%252C%2522clt4b9ftw0003356iqby7t3xv%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0003356iqby7t3xv%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

make the wheel rotating normally( around it's center)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this from this [three.js forum post](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/access-instancedmeshs-sub-instance-origin-and-tranform-with-pivot/61985).

The instancedMesh's sub-instance is already "pivoted", so the solution is to "unPivot". Based on some souce code in [InstancedMesh: Add bounding volumes. by Mugen87 · Pull Request #21507 · mrdoob/three.js · GitHub](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/21507/commits/bd71dd1cf5fb00794077214b2565a066e48fa1a1)
that it is possible to get the sub-instance's volume center as `offset`.And the "unpivot" way is adding a parent pivot to the dummy object,and:

1. sub the dummy's position with `offset`
2. add the parentDummy's position with `offset`
3. update parentDummy's rotation in the loop
4. updating instanceMatrix with dummy's matrixWorld
   here is a working example:

[Instancing Ferrari Demo Justified](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/instancing-ferrari-forked-jk533h?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A124%2C31&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0006356ilo8j1nq4%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0002356iozyiy965%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0003356iqby7t3xv%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0005356i7ho63iz2%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B53.50215844834924%252C46.49784155165076%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clt4b9ftw0002356iozyiy965%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0001356ifhsbd0wi%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4bjvov0002356o4h4z3z2t%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A124%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A31%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A124%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A31%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4c5ym60002356omas7j57d%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A16%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A14%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A16%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A14%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FflatternNode.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0002356iozyiy965%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt4bjvov0002356o4h4z3z2t%2522%257D%252C%2522clt4b9ftw0005356i7ho63iz2%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0004356iu1sz77xr%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0005356i7ho63iz2%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0004356iu1sz77xr%2522%257D%252C%2522clt4b9ftw0003356iqby7t3xv%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt4b9ftw0003356iqby7t3xv%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)
It would be nice if anyone has other better solution..